# Is there an equivalent of the method addEventSource() for resources?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am attempting to use an external function call to render my calendar where view settings, events and resources are passed in as JSON function parameters. I have managed to load both events and view settings correctly using the following function but it would be potentially useful to load in the resources in a similar way.

```
function refreshCalendar(eventsArray, resourceArray, view, startDate) {
calendar.addEventSource(eventsArray);
calendar.addResourceSource = resourceArray; <- This line needs fixing
calendar.changeView(view, startDate);
calendar.render(); }
```